# PHP code showing blank page

Tags: php

I want to send a email with input data from my html page. I am using next php script:

```
<?php
if((isset($_POST['budget']))&&(isset($_POST['type']))) {
    $email_to = "design.er@icloud.com";
    $email_subject = "Design";

    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }


    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['budget']) ||
        !isset($_POST['type'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $email = $_POST['email']; // required
    $budget = $_POST['budget']; // required
    $type = $_POST['type']; // required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // not required
    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Budget: ".clean_string($budget)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Type: ".clean_string($type)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- THERE MY PHP CODE, I REMOVED IT ESPECIALLY FOR STACKOVERFLOW, BUT IT EXIST -->

<?php
}
?>
```

But it doesn't work. When I am clicking on submit - it shows me a blank page. 
I can't understand what the problem is.

Also, I tried next script and it worked perfectly:

```
  <?php
     $to = "xyz@somedomain.com";
     $subject = "This is subject";

     $message = "<b>This is HTML message.</b>";
     $message .= "<h1>This is headline.</h1>";

     $header = "From:abc@somedomain.com \r\n";
     $header .= "Cc:afgh@somedomain.com \r\n";
     $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
     $header .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

     $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);

     if( $retval == true ) {
        echo "Message sent successfully...";
     }else {
        echo "Message could not be sent...";
     }
  ?>
```

Comment: A blank page is usually an internal server error. What does your web servers error log contain?

Comment: You need to be more explicit with the post. Prepare a case. What have you try? If you find something even here and that is not fixing the problem. If you an error on console for example you need to show it. If you give more information it is a little bit better.

Comment: Nothing. I tried this script on another hosting and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I updated my post

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing showing because there is nothing to show.  The only place in the script where there is an effort to display something is if the page is accessed without the proper post variables (in this case displaying the contents of the `died()` method).  At the very bottom of this script there is an html comment with `<!-- HTML CODE HERE -->` and there's nothing there.

Comment: I have html code which to show, I just removed it for stackoverflow and left it with a comment

Comment: Then check your error logs, or enable logging directly for this script.  What do they say?

Comment: I can't check them. It's forbidden function on my host.

Comment: OK.  I'm going to delete my answer in a bit then because it's not going to help you.  But if you're developing sites or managing them and you can't get basic logging information from your host, you really should consider your options in providers.  Having access to error logs and being able to understand them is the first step in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

An absolutely blank page (i.e. even no output when you view the page's source in the browser) usually means that a PHP error occurred and error reporting is turned off. In this case you should take a look into the server's log files, if you can do that. (It might not be available on some hosted platforms.)

Common mistakes for such a "white screen of death" are syntax errors in the PHP script, but yours seems to be OK. However, some host providers disable some functions like the `mail()` function to avoid scripts that send spam emails. In this case, the `mail()` function could cause an internal error which stops the script execution at that point. Since this is before the point where any HTML code is printed in your script, this could be the cause of the error.

Comment: Thank you! My host forbid to see server's log files. 
And, as you can see in my updated post - I can send email with another script.

I just received a message from support, they told me that the error in this piece of code -
<?php
}
?>